# Why would the F# compiler check if the newly created array is null?

Tags: f#

I am playing around with F# and wanted to check how it generates code compared to C# and found a strange line.
I am using dotTrace to decompile code and make C# equivalent. I have also tried to check IL code using LinqPad.

My code is quite small.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let mutable sum = 0
    // 1000 or 997
    //let arr : int array = Array.zeroCreate 997
    //let arr  = Enumerable.Range(0, 997).ToArray()
    let arr :int array = [|0..997|]
    arr |> Array.iter (fun x -> sum <- sum + x)
    printfn "%i" sum
    0
```

And this is what I get.

```
  {
    int func = 0;
    int[] numArray = SeqModule.ToArray<int>(Operators.CreateSequence<int>(Operators.OperatorIntrinsics.RangeInt32(0, 1, 997)));
    if ((object) numArray == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    int length = numArray.Length;
    int index = 0;
    int num1 = length - 1;
    if (num1 >= index)
    {
      do
      {
        int num2 = numArray[index];
        func += num2;
        ++index;
      }
      while (index != num1 + 1);
    }
    PrintfModule.PrintFormatLineToTextWriter<FSharpFunc<int, Unit>>(Console.Out, (PrintfFormat<FSharpFunc<int, Unit>, TextWriter, Unit, Unit>) new PrintfFormat<FSharpFunc<int, Unit>, TextWriter, Unit, Unit, int>("%i")).Invoke(func);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And this is how IL looks like.

```
  // IL_0019: stloc.1      // 'numArray [Range(Instruction(IL_0019 stloc.1)-Instruction(IL_0040 ldloc.1))]'
  // IL_001a: ldloc.1      // 'numArray [Range(Instruction(IL_0019 stloc.1)-Instruction(IL_0040 ldloc.1))]'
  // IL_001b: box          int32[]
  // IL_0020: brfalse.s    IL_0025
  // IL_0022: nop          
  // IL_0023: br.s         IL_0030
  // IL_0025: ldstr        "array"
  // IL_002a: newobj       instance void [mscorlib]System.ArgumentNullException::.ctor(string)
  // IL_002f: throw
```

Compiled using Release, .Net 4.6, FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0, Optimize code, Generate Tail Calls.

I am very curious about the NULL check and cast.

```
(object) numArray == null
```

I do understand why the obj cast is done. The array is not a null and can't be checked without.

I am curious (don't thinks it is a problem) and the question is more about compiler.

1. Why would it be useful to check for null? I am not defining an option type.
2. Under what conditions the exception will fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That check is part of the [implementation of `Array.iter`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs). The compiler just seems not to be smart enough to figure out that `box arg` in this case is never going to be `null`.